# Find a set to show distinguishability with a non-regular language

Tags: automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

I have a language L such that L includes all the concatenations of 2 of 2^k where k is a prime number.

For example, 2^1 = 2, 2^5 = 22222, 2^7 = 2222222

I already know L is irregular because there must exist a set of strings that are pairwise distinguishable with respect to L.

I'm struggling to come up with such a set of strings, however. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question. It's a question about the theory of regular languages.